# Can WCF Have a Default URL without adding whatever.svc?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm currently in the process of converting .asmx web services to a WCF project, but I have multiple needs that I cannot deviate from.

Need 1:  They are not updating their services, it will be a .asmx to wcf call.  I've already researched on how to accept asmx calls, which may produce another question in the future.

Need 2:  The original .asmx service was called using the following url:  `http://webservices-url-here.com/service/`.  This can not change.

.asmx can be set that if there is a default.asmx file, that will be the service being called when a SOAP POST is generated, so the File.asmx after the URL was never specifically called.

Is there an equivalent for WCF?

Comment: A lot of sample WCF applications are set up this way. A google search on "wcf without svc" should give you about a thousand different examples.

Comment: In WCF just URI has no meaning, its endpoint through which you talk to service. You can verywell configure your endpoint address way you want. Offcourse scheme of URI will depend on type of binding you want to use.